# Jetty's custom login service, classloader issue

Tags: java, authentication, jetty, classloader

Related to the question raised @ [Jetty custom LoginService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147918/jetty-custom-loginservice)

So, I figured out somehow after lots of tries that indeed the custom login class should be placed in {jetty.base}/lib/ext folder in order for Jetty to be able to find it by the classloader used.

However, now that the class is loaded I'm having another issue... I gett ClassNotFoundException for the business logic classes that are referred to by the custom login service class. Obviously, the entire purpose of having a custom login service class is so that the login could use some business logic that is within my webapp code... So how come the classloader being used is such that it cannot see the web-inf/lib (and the extra classpath libs) of the webapp?

what am I missing and what should I do?

thanks,
GBa.

Answer (score 0):

From this mailing list - http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/Jetty-custom-LoginService-question-td4966621.html, for your problem it says

> Make a new jetty base directory for this. Put your webapp into it.
>   Enable modules such as http,  security, deploy, and ext and any others
>   you might need   (take a look at $jetty.home/demo-base/ to get some
>   ideas).  Put your jar with the LoginService impl into your jetty base
>   lib/ext directory.  Then, take the lines from your
>   WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml file that sets up the login service and put them
>   into a context xml file for your webapp so they are read first, rather
>   than last as is the case with jetty-web.xml when configuring your
>   webapp.

I am assuming you have already put your custom LoginService inside the `${jetty.base}/lib/ext` folder

After that you should also create a create `context.xml` in your webapp which contains the information about the extra classpath libs by taking reference of `jetty-web.xml` and following the steps in this link - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-classloading.html#adding-extra-classpaths

Start your server and this should work

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. As I mentioned, the LoginService is loaded by the server classloader not by the webapp and thus, using extra classpath or any other definition on the webapp won't work...

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to Jetty-users mailing list I got an answer...

you can read all about it here:
https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg08262.html